# Вывод данных страницы из бд Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Люди добрые, подскажите пожалуйста. Не могу разобраться как в Laravel вытянуть из БД данные страницы(Тайтл, описание и тд). Передаю значение url в контроллер:

```
Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@page')->where('url', '[a-z]+');
```

В контроллере пытаюсь получить все необходимые данные страницы:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $category;
    protected $page;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }

    public function page($url) {
        $page = $this->page->find($url);
        $title = $page->title;
        echo $title;

        return view('page', ['catalog' => $catalog, 'page_show' => $page_show, 'page' => $page, 'title' => $title]);
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pages';

}
```

Поля таблицы: id|url|title|description|created_at|updated_at
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object  - получаю на выходе...

Не могу найти примеры, возможно плохо ищу, очень буду благодарен за дельный совет.

Answer (score 1):

В строке `this->page->find($url)` вы пытаетесь получить запись по `$url`. Но, в документации сказано, что метод Eloquent Collection [`find`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-find) делает выборку по **primary key**.

> The find method finds a model that has a given **primary key**

Вам стоит попробовать изменить primary key через `protected $primaryKey = 'url';` в модели или получить конкретную запись через `Page::where('url', $url)->get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Я был в той же ситуации в моём проекте! Всё просто: Доступ к постам, страницам и их данным в Ларавел происходит не по url, а через БД и id. url нельзя передать в адрес (иначе получится винегрет, url в квадрате).

В вашем случае нужно передавать id, которое предварительно нужно присвоить в ссылке к странице. Вот так в showpage.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($page as $pages)
<a href="{{ route('page.show', ['page' => $pages->id]) }}">ссылка</a>
@endforeach
```

а роут, который будет принимать id вот такой:

```
Route::get('/page/{page}', 'PageController@page')->name('page.show');
```

И тогда контроллер такой:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function page($id){
        $page = Page::find($id);
        $title = $page->title;
        $description = $page->description;

        return view('page', ['title' => $title, 'description' => $description]);
    }
}
```